# Indexing a Word in a Substring of a List

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out how to index substrings of a list.
Say we're given the list:

```
shoes = ['Oxford shoes', 'Casual shoes', 'Tennis shoes', 'Oxford 
        shoes']
```

For indexing a normal list I would do (assigned variable)[index value]. So for this case, if I wanted to find where 'Casual shoes' fell under the list shoes, I would do:

```
shoes[1] or shoes[-3]
```

But how would I index say the word 'Casual' in the substring 'Casual shoes' of the list shoes?

Comment: If you want to index a substring you will need to use a different data structure. But if you just want to access it you can do something like `shoes[1].split(' ')[0]`

Answer (score 1):

To find the index of the string containing a substring you can use:

```
casual_index = shoes.index(next(w for w in shoes if 'Casual' in w))
```

This returns: `1`

Then you can split it to get the word as @Thom mentioned in their comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply check if what you want is in the strings.

```py
shoes = ['Oxford shoes', 'Casual shoes', 'Tennis shoes', 'Oxford shoes']

def find_index(elements, text):
    results = []
    for i, element in enumerate(elements):
        if text in element:
            results.append(i)
    return results

print(find_index(shoes, "Casual"))
[1]
```